# Multi-line On Variable DataSet On Photoshop (Text-File)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, photoshop-script

### There is an issue to import a text variable from a text file.

Data set 1: Item 1, Life is Good, Canada

Data set 2: Item 2, Never Stop Dreaming, USA

### But I wanna Make a Break between the text like That :

-Life

-is

-Good

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then all you need to do is split and join a string with a carriage return "\n":

```
var Item_1 = "Life is Good, Canada";
var Item_2 = "Never Stop Dreaming, USA";

Item_1 = Item_1.split(" ").join("\n");
Item_2 = Item_2.split(" ").join("\n");
```

which becomes:

```
Life
is
Good,
Canada

Never
Stop
Dreaming,
USA
```